# How to run heavy query?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to destroy all experiments that has user_id equals nil

```
Experiment.destroy_all(:user_id=>nil)
```

But, it takes long time, and I end up with application error

```
 ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:14 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
2014-05-04T12:31:39.478999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/en/experiments host=dcaclab.com request_id=908575f9-3dcf-47da-8f53-a22fe4f8f48c fwd="86.108.98.180" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=15549ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-05-04T12:31:39.479594+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2014-05-04T12:31:39.479439 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 14 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
```

So, how to run such a query?
Also, how can I run it using heroku command line?

Comment: Have you tried using batch methods find_each or find_in_batches.

Comment: I will check that, but would I need a background worker?

Comment: Not really. Open your rails console in sandbox mode and try this. rails c --sandbox ; Then write your query Experiment.where(:user_id => nil).find_each {|experiment| experiment.destroy }

Comment: Can I rails c --sandbox while my app is at heroku?

Comment: I have not tried in heroku but you can give a try. Hopefully it will work.